# Hook a creation of a visible window c++

Tags: c++, winapi, events

I want to be alerted every time a visible (something with graphical interface) window is created in c++. I've thought something like that:

```
    HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook0 = SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE,
    NULL, WinEventProcCallback, 0, 0,
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
```

And:

```
VOID CALLBACK WinEventProcCallback(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, 
DWORD dwEvent, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread,    DWORD dwmsEventTime)
if (idObject == OBJID_WINDOW && dwEvent == EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
    {
       // ...
    }
 }
```

But it doesn't work. Since I've observed that by removing 'IsWindowVisible' the code manages to catch all window creation I've thought that maybe at creation the flag visible is not set yet, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: `EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW` maybe?

Comment: So it **does** work, but you are filtering out invisible objects. At the point where `WinEventProcCallback` is called, the window object has been created (the kernel-controlled structures are initialized), but the visual doesn't yet exist. Calling `IsWindowVisible` will always return `FALSE` at this stage.

Comment: IInespecable,  I got it,  but how to solve the problem?  I am not sure and i can t try it now but I remember that EVENT_OBJECT_SHOWN isn t working properly...